# nodejs spawning processes in shared hosting, causing it to crash

Tags: node.js, express, shared-hosting, pm2, forever

We are renting a shared hosting server, and we run our nodejs/express app on it. The problem is that we are limited in the number of processes allowed (30), and nodejs spawns some processes from time to time. When we reach 30 processes, the server stops responding and we have to reboot it.

We tried to run our app using pm2, but it created too much processes. So we landed on "forever", which seems to create less processes, but the issue is still occuring. We're not experts in nodejs so we have no idea why this is happening, if anyone knows it would be a life saver !